Git Guardian on dummy data
I have a Firebase project where I have dummy accounts to test locally. To avoid creating the accounts each time I start the Firebase Emulator, Once I have the accounts, I export everything. Since they are dummy accounts, it's safe to commit this export. The problem is that Git Guardian detects it as a breach (For some reason it started recently, before it didn't trigger, even when the export was already there)

Thank you in advance 
What I want to achieve:

Be allowed to commit this export to avoid my teammates to create test accounts each time the Firebase Emulator is started.
Keep Git Guardian checking for the repo, just no within the "export" folder.

Is that possible? If so, how?
